# Building htop from source in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, htop

I am trying to build [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) from the source package (latest stable) under Cygwin on  Windows 7 64bit. I am following the instructions given in README, but I'm hitting the following error when I run the make script:

```
Administrator@x230-WIN7 ~/tmp/htop-1.0.3
$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Administrator/tmp/htop-1.0.3'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -rdynamic -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -g -O2 -MT htop-AvailableMetersPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-AvailableMetersPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-AvailableMetersPanel.o `test -f 'AvailableMetersPanel.c' || echo './'`AvailableMetersPanel.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rdynamic’
Makefile:467: recipe for target 'htop-AvailableMetersPanel.o' failed
make[1]: *** [htop-AvailableMetersPanel.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Administrator/tmp/htop-1.0.3'
Makefile:292: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

All suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) author here — htop has a lot of platform-specific code, so porting it is [not a matter of simply recompiling it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5GamptmWeA). The current version of htop does not support Cygwin. The latest [release](http://hisham.hm/htop/releases) version, [2.0.1](http://hisham.hm/htop/releases/2.0.1/), supports Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD and OpenBSD.

I'm happy to [accept patches](http://github.com/hishamhm/htop/) if someone writes a Cygwin port, though!

Comment: Hey, could you please share any insights on missing ends in Cygwin?